# Laravel 8: Call to database function

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using a Laravel 8 for website developement, and on the next part of code, I execute a query:

```
$assig = DB::table('table')
->where('table.column', '=', "oneValue")
->select('anfunctionOnDatabase(2,table.columDesc)')
->get();
```

but it no works.

How I need call to database function on laravel?

Thanks

Comment: if you want to use functions of the database then you should use raw db for laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use selectRaw()

like this;

```
$assig = DB::table('table')
    ->where('table.column', '=', "oneValue")
    ->selectRaw('anfunctionOnDatabase(2,table.columDesc)')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use : DB::raw :

```
$assig = DB::table('table')
->where('table.column', '=', "oneValue")
->select(DB::raw("anfunctionOnDatabase(2,table.columDesc)"))
->get();
```